# Nice fast lazy loading of uiLabels on a long uiScrollView

Tags: performance, tags, uiscrollview, lazy-loading, uilabel

I have about 200 uiLabels on a long (92000) uiScrollView, I'm getting fairly low performance when scrolling. I would like to try lazy loading. Please could I have some ideas for a nice fast method, I have seen a fair few different approaches to this, there must be one that stands out as a fast one?

I am loading my uiLabels into an array from a plist, this array runs and adds the uiLabels to the scroll View in my (void)viewDidLoad.
I could easily add tags at that stage?

I expect to put the clever bit into my (void) scrollViewDidScroll

thanks for any ideas...

Answer (score 0):

You could try an approach similar to UITableView cell loading and reusing.
If, for example, a screen would be filled by 10 labels, only create and add 15 labels to the scrollview, and as soon as a label is no longer visible at all (which you can find by comparing label's frame with the scroll view content offset), just reuse the label by updating its frame, and its content, according to the new position where a new label will be visible, instead of creating a new object.
I'm sure you will get both a significant performance increase and less memory used also, by using 15 labels instead of 200.

Hope this helps.